# undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass for comment

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am using Ajax to create comment in my article show page, and it works perfect. Now, I want to show the errors for the comment by using Ajax too. However, now I get the error:

> undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass

I added the method new in my comments_controller.rb to make sure the application know the instance variable comment does exist, but the problem is still there. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

**comments/create.js.erb**:

```
$('#comments').append("<%= j render @comment %>").hide().fadeIn('slow');

// Empty the form
$('#comment_name').val("");
$('#comment_body').val("");

<% if @comment.errors.any? %>
  (".comments-section").html('<%= j(render :partial => 'shared/errors', :object => comment) %>');
<% end %>
```

**comment.rb**:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :body, presence: true, length: { minimum: 10 }
  acts_as_votable
  belongs_to :article
end
```

**comments_controller.rb**:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_article
  before_action :set_comment, only: [:destroy]
  before_action :login_like, only: [:upvote, :downvote]

  def new
    @comment = @article.comments.build
  end

  def create
    @comment = @article.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:name, :body))
    if @comment.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to(@article) }
        format.js # render 'create.js.erb'
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to(@article) }
        format.js { render status: :500 }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    if @comment.destroy
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to(article_path(@article)) }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

  def upvote
    if @comment.upvote_from current_user
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to(:back) }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

  def downvote
    if @comment.downvote_from current_user
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to(:back) }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def set_article
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
  end

  def set_comment
    @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
  end

  def login_like
    unless user_signed_in?
      flash[:danger] = 'You must log in to like or dislike comments!'
    end
  end
end
```

**comments/_form.html.erb**:

```
<%= render 'shared/errors', obj: @comment %>

<%= simple_form_for([@article, @article.comments.build], remote: true) do |f| %>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <%= f.label :name, class: "form-control-label" %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Anyname..." %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <%= f.label :body, class: "form-control-label" %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <%= f.text_area :body, rows: 10, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Write a comment..." %>
    </div>
  </div >
  <br>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-secondary" %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**views/shared/_errors.html.erb**:

```
<% if obj.errors.any? %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header card-inverse card-danger">
          <div class="card-title">
            <%= pluralize(obj.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this article from being saved:
            </div>
            <div class="card-text">
              <ul>
                <% obj.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                  <li><%= message %></li>
                <% end %>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**articles/show.html.erb**:

```
<div class="card col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 comments-section glassy-comment">
    <h2 style="padding-top: 7px;">
      Comment
    </h2>
    <hr>
    <div id="comments">
      <%= render @article.comments %>
    </div>
    <h3>Add a comment:</h3>
    <div class="comment-wrapper">
      <%= render 'comments/form' %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show how are you creating the comments in the article show page?

Comment: @Pavan, yes, I've just updated the articles/show.html.erb file, please take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are displaying the `form` to add a comment in the `articles/show.html.erb`, so `@comment` need to defined in `articles#show` action

```
#artcles_controller

def show
  @comment = Comment.new
end
```

And you need to pass it in `form` as `local params` to the partial

```
<%= render 'comments/form', comment: @comment %>
```

And finally change the below line in `comments/_form.html.erb`

```
<%= render 'shared/errors', obj: @comment %>
```

to

```
<%= render 'shared/errors', obj: comment %>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It doesn't show any errors anymore. Although, when I tried to submit a blank comment, it didn't show the errors that I validate in my comment model. I still mark your answer as a solution. Have a nice day.

Comment: @FinalFantasyVIII What are the validations that you have in the Comment model? Update it in your question.

Comment: I have just updated the comment.rb, create.erb.js, and my comments_controller.rb files. Please take a quick look and correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting a `@comment` only before `destroy`:

```
before_action :set_comment, only: [:destroy]
```

but you use it also in: `upvote`, `downvote`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But, I dont quite understand how it can cause the problem. Could you be more be specific? The upvote, and downvote method still work fine by the way.